# element.firstChild don't work in IDE but in Sandbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jsx

I found a problem, that I can't explain myself. Short story long: I tried to build a native draggable slider with react and positioned it in the middle of the screen. At least in my Codesandbox file. There I used this code:

```
    const windowWidth = window.innerWidth / 2;
    const itemWidth = track.firstChild.offsetWidth / 2;
    const offsetPercent = ((windowWidth - itemWidth) / window.innerWidth) * 100;

    track.style.left = `${offsetPercent}%`;
```

In codesandbox it works fine as hell. Everything like I like it to be. Now I wanted to add this test code to my real project. Build with NextJs, React & IDE VS Code.

But there I'll always get this error: "TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'offsetWidth')" [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dy9Ro.png)

I can't explain myself why. The whole code is the same like in Codesandbox.

---

Here's a link to the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/draggable-example-kwrfp1?file=/src/slider.jsx)

Like I said, i tried the code in Codesandbox, where it runs perfectly. But in my local IDE, VS Code I get this error message. Therefore it's the same code I can't explain it myself, why I'm getting the error..

Comment: Did you try to run `npm run build` or `tsc` in your directory? Also checking the Typescript versions in your project and in the sandbox could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining), using `?`.

If the object accessed or function called using this operator is undefined or null, the expression short circuits and evaluates to undefined instead of throwing an error.

```
const windowWidth = window.innerWidth / 2;
const itemWidth = track?.firstChild?.offsetWidth / 2;
const offsetPercent = ((windowWidth - itemWidth) / window.innerWidth) * 100;

track.style.left = `${offsetPercent}%`;
```

Answer (score 0):

In frameworks like Next, which is competely SSR, components are rendered twice - once on the server and once in the browser. For this reason, you must make your components server-safe. For example, `window` is not available in the server. And, likely, whatever `track` is could also not be found.

Even if it could, and even if you're on a browser, `track` could end up being empty.
By using `track.firstChild.offsetHeight` you expect `firstChild` to exist - but what if, for any reason, it doesn't?

To do this, consider it not being there in your code.

```js
const child = track.firstChild;
if (!firstChild) return;
const itemWidth = firstChild.offsetWidth / 2;
```

Or, to be more concise, use optional chaining:

```js
const itemWidth = track.firstChild?.offsetWidth / 2;
```